# Moving an anchor point on an svg without it affecting the height of the svg?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, anchor

I have a react component in which I have displayed an svg with a few anchor points. At the widest point of the shape is one anchor point and I want the user to be able to move said anchor point without it affecting any of the rest of the svg. So the height would remain the same and the user would move the width up and down essentially on the border of the svg being able to shift the widest point. Anyone know if this is possible?

```
  const [halfPathRight, setHalfPathRight] = useState(`m.25.25c2,1.4,10.7,8.9,10.7,33.4,0,25.7-6.4,38.6-6.4,38.6,0,0-2.9-.3-4.3-3`)
  const [sliderAnchorHeight, setSliderAnchorHeight] = useState(33.4)

  const handleAnchorHeight = (e) => {
    setAnchorHeight(parseFloat(e.target.value));

    setSliderAnchorHeight(parseFloat(e.target.value) * 10);

    setHalfPathRight(`m.25.25c2,1.4,10.7,8.9,10.7,${sliderAnchorHeight},0,25.7-6.4,38.6-6.4,38.6,0,0-2.9-.3-4.3-3`)
  
  }

  return (

    Slider anchor height
          <input type="range" id="right-wing" name="right-wing" value={anchorHeight} min="2" max="4" step={0.01} onChange={handleAnchorHeight}/>

            <div className="" style={{ marginRight: '200px' }}>
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="500" width="100" viewBox="0 0 11.2 100" style={{ marginLeft: "-22px" }}>
              <defs>
                <style>{`.cls-1 {
                  fill: none;
                  stroke: #000;
                  stroke-linecap: round;
                  stroke-linejoin: round;
                  stroke-width: .5px;
                }`}</style>
              </defs>
              <g transform="translate(0, 10)">
              <path className="cls-1" d={halfPathRight}/>
              </g>
            </svg>
            </div>

)
```

Sort of have something like this right now but the length between the middle point and the top anchor point is diminishing and increasing based on my slider movement.

Comment: You need to use absolute commands  `M 0.3 0.3
C 2.3 1.6 10.9 9.2 10.9 33.6
C 10.9 59.3 4.5 72.3 4.5 72.3
C 4.5 72.3 1.6 72 0.2 69.3`  - otherwise all following commands will be shifted relative to the changed y coordinates. You can convert your svg e.g. with [svg-path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

Comment: Oh thank you. I didn’t know about this. I will try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The comment above indeed works! Converting the relative path to absolute allows one to move the anchor point without it affecting the rest of the svg. And I used the [svg-path-editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/) recommended by @herrstrietzel.